# Deploying SQLite DB to iPad app (via iTunes?)

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, sqlite, itunes

I'm solving an iPad app architecture for a client and I've come to these conclusions:

- I will develop a simple, **locally run** CMS where the client can edit content
- The client can from this CMS export the content to a SQLite DB file
- I will develop an iPad application that reads and presents this SQLite DB
- The client must be able to update the SQLite database file
- The iPad application must not be dependent on an internet connection

My question is really, can my client copy this DB file from his/her laptop (Mac if needed) via iTunes, so that the iPad application gets an updated SQLite database?

I'll probably use Monotouch for development, but that shouldn't make a difference. This is strictly an iPad app, but I've included iPhone as a tag since they consociate in many aspects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable the `UIFileSharingEnabled` property in the apps `Info.plist` then the Documents folder becomes available when you connect the iPad to iTunes. You can copy files to/from the device this way.

Comment: Will my iPad app be able to attach to and read from a SQLite database file in the Documents folder?

Comment: No, you would copy the database file to your applications Documents folder. Your iPad can't access the PCs file system.

Comment: OK... I think it's very obvious that I was referring to the Documents folder on the iPad from the iPad app. Not some strange "access-the-laptop-from-the-iPad"-folder. Anyway, it sounds like I could access and read from the copied SQLite DB File from the iPad app. I will try to create a proof-of-concept using this technique, and accept your answer if it worked.